# groovy script template is failing after changing the jenkins job folder using folder plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy

```
     <% def printStatusRecursively(cause) {
    if (cause.class.toString().contains("UpstreamCause")) {
        def projectName = cause.getUpstreamProject() 
        def number = cause.getUpstreamRun().number 
        upstreamJob = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem(projectName)
        upbuild = upstreamJob.getBuildByNumber(number)%>

        <TR>
        <TD>${projectName}</TD>
        <TD>${upbuild.result}</TD>
        <TD><A href="${rooturl}${upbuild.url}">${rooturl}${upbuild.url}</A>     </TD>
        </TR>
        <%
        for (upCause in cause.upstreamCauses) {
          printStatusRecursively(upCause)
    }        }
    }%>
<%
for (cause in build.causes)
{
  printStatusRecursively(cause)
}%>
```

i use a grrovy script similar to the below link "https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/groovy-html.template". I use it part of my jenkins email-ext plugin it was succusful for many jobs, but suddenly when i moved my jobs to the a folder using folder plugin , then it started failing with this error:
Exception raised during template rendering: Cannot invoke method "getBuildByNumber() on null object java.lang.NullPointerException: ".

Please some help me

Answer (score 2):

You should use [jenkins.model.Jenkins.getItemByFullName(fullName)](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#getItemByFullName(java.lang.String))
where `fullName` is a string like `foldername/jobname` - a hierarchical name of a job which includes all the parent folders separated with a slash `/` (like a filesystem path). [getItemByFullName](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#getItemByFullName(java.lang.String)) works both for jobs inside and outside folders.

Say I have the following structure:

```
Jenkins
 |-Job_A
 |-Folder
    |-Job_B
    |-Nested_Folder
       |-Job_C
```

Code sample:

```
def job
def j = jenkins.model.Jenkins

//To get `Job_A`:
job = j.getItemByFullName('Job_A')

//To get `Job_B`:
job = j.getItemByFullName('Folder/Job_B')

//To get `Job_C`:
job = j.getItemByFullName('Folder/Nested_Folder/Job_C')
```

More info on Jenkins wiki: [Hierarchical projects support](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Hierarchical+projects+support#Hierarchicalprojectssupport-Expansionofabstraction%3Afullname)

Comment: Had a similar issue and this fixed it.  I think this should be marked as the correct answer.